# Flutter - Change text style as long as the user pressing the widget

Tags: flutter, dart, gesturedetector

I have a simple `Text` Widget that it's supposed to "light up" (change the text and icon color for as long as the user is pressing down on it) when the user lifts up his finger color reverts to default.
I know that it has something to do with `GestureDetector`, `onLongPressStart`& `onLongPressEnd`but I can't figure out how to exactly go from there!

This is the widget:

```
GestureDetector(
    onLongPressStart: /** change text & icon color */,
    onLongPressEnd: /** revert to default text & icon color */,
    child: Row(
        children: [
            Text("visit us"),
            SizedBox(width: 6.0),
            Icon(FeatherIcons.arrowRightCircle,),
        ],
    ),
),
```

How exactly can I achieve that kind of logic ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyWidget({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {

  Color textColor = Colors.black;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
         onLongPressStart: (val){
            setState((){
              textColor = Colors.red;
            });
         },
         onLongPressEnd: (val){
           setState((){
              textColor = Colors.black;
            });
          },
         child: Row(
         children: [
            Text("visit us",style:TextStyle(color:textColor)),
            SizedBox(width: 6.0),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When you are changing the already defined variable inside the setState it rebuilds the widget with new Value, in this Case it is `textColor` but you can have many others like this other example.

suppose we have following variables defined before build function:

```
Color textColor = Colors.black;
String text = "initial Text";
```

`setState` function will look like this:

```
setState((){
  textColor = Colors.red;
  text = "new Text";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

without having tested it, i would try to set a variable on longPressStart and unset it on longPressEnd.
Then, the child-array of the row can be something like:

`if(longPressVariable == true) then return [TextWithStyle1] else return [TextWithStyle2]`